# calling javascript function from SVG file

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have SVG file, it consists of multiple links. Once user clicks on the link, page should display results.

SVG file contains Different Genetic information, need to show multiple results.

Onclick I need to invoke a JavaScript function to process the result. But javascript:myfunction(); is not invoking when I click on SVG file. Kindly suggest any alternative solutions or any workaround.

I think question is not very clear. updating information

I have SVG file. save it as mysvg.svg file in your system.

```
<svg>
        <g id="US">
                <rect x='10' y='10' fill='#000000' height='100' width='100'></rect>
        </g>
        <g id="CA">
                <rect x='150' y='10' fill='#0000FF' height='100' width='100'></rect>
        </g>
    <a xlink:href="#crisp"> 
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="164.05078125" style="fill:none; stroke:none" height="100" pointer-events="fill" />
    </a>
</svg>
```

My HTML file.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function() {
               alert('hi');
            }); 
        loadSVGasXML();     
    });

    function loadSVGasXML() {
        var SVGFile="myfile.svg"

        var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
        function handler(){

            var svgDiv = document.all.svgDiv;
            if(loadXML.readyState == 4 && loadXML.status == 0) {            
                    var xmlString=loadXML.responseText
                    svgDiv.innerHTML=xmlString              
                    fitSVGinDiv()           
            }
        }
        if (loadXML != null) {
            loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
            loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
            loadXML.send();
        }
    }

    function fitSVGinDiv(){
        var divWH=60

        var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]

        var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
        var bbw=bb.width
        var bbh=bb.height

        //--use greater of bbw vs bbh--
        if(bbw>=bbh)
        var factor=bbw/divWH
        else
        var factor=bbh/divWH

        var vbWH=divWH*factor

        var vbX=(bbw-vbWH)/2
        var vbY=(bbh-vbWH)/2

        mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",vbX+" "+vbY+" "+vbWH+" "+vbWH)

        mySVG.setAttribute("width","100%")
        mySVG.setAttribute("height","100%")
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <!--<a href="#crisp"> hi </a>-->
    <div id="svgDiv">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

        <a id="crisp"> hello</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

Please add more so that it looks as if long page. I want to capture onclick function of anchor tag in my svg file

Comment: Add some code. Try to use `onclick` instead of `javascript:` URI Schema.

Comment: I think question is not very clear.

Comment: Can you make your SVG code more readable by properly indenting it?

Comment: If i place this svg (changing the x and y atributes to make the rect to be inside the screen) in a plain html with a defined myfunction() just after the svg it works to me in firefox. Maybe your problem it comes from other side. Could you give more details?

Comment: I am manipulating (width, height) svg file for fitting into my html page. Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152195/redering-svg-file-in-html-page/21172867?noredirect=1#21172867 . I am using HTML 4.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, sorry I don't know how to format the code. Just now learned. Please look at the code. this is exactly depicts my problem. @user688877 please look at this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different things are happening here. First the solution to your problem:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadSVGasXML();     
});

function loadSVGasXML() {
    var SVGFile="myfile.svg";

    var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function handler(){

        var svgDiv = document.getElementById("svgDiv");
        if(loadXML.readyState == 4 && loadXML.status == 200) {            
            var xmlString=loadXML.responseText;
            svgDiv.innerHTML=xmlString;
            $("a").click(function() {
               alert('hi');
            });            
            fitSVGinDiv();        
        }
    }
    if (loadXML != null) {
        loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
        loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
        loadXML.send();
    }
}

function fitSVGinDiv(){
    var divWH=60;

    var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

    var bb=mySVG.getBBox();
    var bbw=bb.width;
    var bbh=bb.height;

    //--use greater of bbw vs bbh--
    if(bbw>=bbh)
        var factor=bbw/divWH;
    else
        var factor=bbh/divWH;

    var vbWH=divWH*factor;

    var vbX=(bbw-vbWH)/2;
    var vbY=(bbh-vbWH)/2;

    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",vbX+" "+vbY+" "+vbWH+" "+vbWH);

    mySVG.setAttribute("width","100%");
    mySVG.setAttribute("height","100%");
}
</script>

<!--<a href="#crisp"> hi </a>-->
<div id="svgDiv">
</div>
<br>
<br>
  <a id="crisp"> hello</a>
</div>
```

Now the explanation:

```
    $("a").click(function() {
       alert('hi');
    });
```

What it does, more and less,  is to look for all the `<a>` html elements that is in your web right now and bind to them the onclick event to say "hi" to everybody.

At the beging there is no svg and so there is no "a" elements and you do the binding. Then the svg is loaded by `loadSVGasXML();` and the html content is changed. New  tags are added. But this  tags are attached to the web page after to bind the event width `$("a").click(function() {alert('hi'});` and so this new  onclick events haven't been binded yet. So what you need to do is to make the event bind whenever you change your web content dynamically after everything is loaded. So you need to place the binding inside the handler callback function.

Second you are using an old way to get the DOM. `document.all.svgDiv` it dates from a dark times before the Roman Empire (just joking) where to develop anything related to the web was a pain in the ass. In those wretched times every browser got's they own way to access  the DOM. In our situation this is the way used long time ago to access the DOM object in IE. Fortunately nowadays everything have changed to better and there are better ways to access the DOM which are supported by all the browsers. If you want to access a DOM element by an id using raw javascript i suggest you to always use `document.getElementById("svgDiv");` .

Finally it comes the `loadXML.status`. When the request have been successful the status is 200 not 0.

Probably those lasts you may already know it and are just a copy & paste mistake. Just pointing to it. Wish this may be helpful to you.