# Call JavaScript function from SVG file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a SVG file and a JavaScript file.

In my SVG file I have some code, but it is this small amount of code I'm wondering about:

```
<g id="zoomButton">
    <g onclick="zoom()" transform="scale(x,y)">
         <rect x="640" y="20" width="140" height="40"
               style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:2" />
         <text x="710" y="49"
               style="fill:red;font-size:25px;text-anchor:middle">Zoom</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

You see that I want the function `zoom()` to be called when this button is clicked.

Now, in my JavaScript file, I have this function called `zoom()`:

```
function zoom() {
    alert("heyho");
}
```

However, this function is not triggered when I press the button created in the SVG file. I only get the error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: zoom is not defined
```

I just want to be able to make that JavaScript function to be called when I press this button.

Furthermore, since this is a zoom-function after all and I want to do some scaling, how do I access the x and y inside `transform="scale(x,y)` in the `zoomButton` in the SVG file from the JavaScript file?

Edit:

The full code in the SVG file is as follows (game.svg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="800px" height="600px"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:a="http://www.adobe.com/svg10-extensions" a:timeline="independent"
     onload="top.load(evt)">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="gameareaclip">
      <rect x="20" y="20" width="600" height="560"/>
    </clipPath>
    <pattern id="background_pattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:purple"/>
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="8" style="fill:black"/>
    </pattern>
    <radialGradient id="player_color">
      <stop offset="0.0" style="stop-color:yellow;stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="0.8" style="stop-color:yellow;stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="1.0" style="stop-color:orange;stop-opacity:1"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#background_pattern);stroke:orange;stroke-width:4" />

  <rect x="20" y="20" width="600" height="560" style="fill:black;stroke:red;stroke-width:5" />

  <!-- Add your button here -->

  <g id="zoomKnapp">
  <g onclick="zoom()" transform="scale(x,y)">
    <rect x="640" y="20" width="140" height="40"
          style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:2" />
    <text x="710" y="49"
          style="fill:red;font-size:25px;text-anchor:middle">Zoom</text>
  </g>
</g>

  <g style="clip-path:url(#gameareaclip)">
    <g transform="translate(20,20)">
      <g id="gamearea" transform="translate(0,0)" width="600" height="560">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="560" style="fill:lightgrey" />

        <g id="platforms">

          <!-- Add your platforms here -->

  <rect id="svg_37" height="20" width="300" y="100" x="0" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#5fbf00"/>
  <rect id="svg_38" height="20" width="300" y="170" x="300" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#5fbf00"/>
  <rect id="svg_39" height="20" width="300" y="240" x="0" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#5fbf00"/>
  <rect id="svg_40" height="20" width="300" y="310" x="300" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#5fbf00"/>
  <rect id="svg_41" height="20" width="300" y="380" x="0" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#5fbf00"/>
  <rect id="svg_42" height="20" width="300" y="450" x="300" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#5fbf00"/>

        </g>

        <g id="player">
          <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" style="fill:url(#player_color);stroke:black;stroke-width:2"/>
          <ellipse cx="15" cy="15" rx="3" ry="6" style="fill:black"/>
          <ellipse cx="25" cy="15" rx="3" ry="6" style="fill:black"/>
          <path d="M10,25 l20,0 q0,8 -10,8 t-10,-8" style="fill:orange;stroke:black;stroke-black:2"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The HTML file (game.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>SVG Game</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center">
    <embed src="game.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="800" height="600" />
</body>

</html>
```

The JavaScript (game.js) code:

```
// The point and size class used in this program
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = (x)? parseFloat(x) : 0.0;
    this.y = (y)? parseFloat(y) : 0.0;
}

function Size(w, h) {
    this.w = (w)? parseFloat(w) : 0.0;
    this.h = (h)? parseFloat(h) : 0.0;
}

// Helper function for checking intersection between two rectangles
function intersect(pos1, size1, pos2, size2) {
    return (pos1.x < pos2.x + size2.w && pos1.x + size1.w > pos2.x &&
            pos1.y < pos2.y + size2.h && pos1.y + size1.h > pos2.y);
}


function zoom() {
    alert("heiho");
}

// The player class used in this program
function Player() {
    this.node = svgdoc.getElementById("player");
    this.position = PLAYER_INIT_POS;
    this.motion = motionType.NONE;
    this.verticalSpeed = 0;
}

Player.prototype.isOnPlatform = function() {
    var platforms = svgdoc.getElementById("platforms");
    for (var i = 0; i < platforms.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = platforms.childNodes.item(i);
        if (node.nodeName != "rect") continue;

        var x = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("x"));
        var y = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("y"));
        var w = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("width"));
        var h = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("height"));

        if (((this.position.x + PLAYER_SIZE.w > x && this.position.x < x + w) ||
             ((this.position.x + PLAYER_SIZE.w) == x && this.motion == motionType.RIGHT) ||
             (this.position.x == (x + w) && this.motion == motionType.LEFT)) &&
            this.position.y + PLAYER_SIZE.h == y) return true;
    }
    if (this.position.y + PLAYER_SIZE.h == SCREEN_SIZE.h) return true;

    return false;
}

Player.prototype.collidePlatform = function(position) {
    var platforms = svgdoc.getElementById("platforms");
    for (var i = 0; i < platforms.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = platforms.childNodes.item(i);
        if (node.nodeName != "rect") continue;

        var x = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("x"));
        var y = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("y"));
        var w = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("width"));
        var h = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("height"));
        var pos = new Point(x, y);
        var size = new Size(w, h);

        if (intersect(position, PLAYER_SIZE, pos, size)) {
            position.x = this.position.x;
            if (intersect(position, PLAYER_SIZE, pos, size)) {
                if (this.position.y >= y + h)
                    position.y = y + h;
                else
                    position.y = y - PLAYER_SIZE.h;
                this.verticalSpeed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

Player.prototype.collideScreen = function(position) {
    if (position.x < 0) position.x = 0;
    if (position.x + PLAYER_SIZE.w > SCREEN_SIZE.w) position.x = SCREEN_SIZE.w - PLAYER_SIZE.w;
    if (position.y < 0) {
        position.y = 0;
        this.verticalSpeed = 0;
    }
    if (position.y + PLAYER_SIZE.h > SCREEN_SIZE.h) {
        position.y = SCREEN_SIZE.h - PLAYER_SIZE.h;
        this.verticalSpeed = 0;
    }
}


//
// Below are constants used in the game
//
var PLAYER_SIZE = new Size(40, 40);         // The size of the player
var SCREEN_SIZE = new Size(600, 560);       // The size of the game screen
var PLAYER_INIT_POS  = new Point(0, 0);     // The initial position of the player

var MOVE_DISPLACEMENT = 5;                  // The speed of the player in motion
var JUMP_SPEED = 15;                        // The speed of the player jumping
var VERTICAL_DISPLACEMENT = 1;              // The displacement of vertical speed

var GAME_INTERVAL = 25;                     // The time interval of running the game


//
// Variables in the game
//
var motionType = {NONE:0, LEFT:1, RIGHT:2}; // Motion enum

var svgdoc = null;                          // SVG root document node
var player = null;                          // The player object
var gameInterval = null;                    // The interval
var zoom = 1.0;                             // The zoom level of the screen


//
// The load function for the SVG document
//
function load(evt) {
    // Set the root node to the global variable
    svgdoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

    // Attach keyboard events
    svgdoc.documentElement.addEventListener("keydown", keydown, false);
    svgdoc.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", keyup, false);

    // Remove text nodes in the 'platforms' group
    cleanUpGroup("platforms", true);

    // Create the player
    player = new Player();

    // Start the game interval
    gameInterval = setInterval("gamePlay()", GAME_INTERVAL);
}


//
// This function removes all/certain nodes under a group
//
function cleanUpGroup(id, textOnly) {
    var node, next;
    var group = svgdoc.getElementById(id);
    node = group.firstChild;
    while (node != null) {
        next = node.nextSibling;
        if (!textOnly || node.nodeType == 3) // A text node
            group.removeChild(node);
        node = next;
    }
}


//
// This is the keydown handling function for the SVG document
//
function keydown(evt) {
    var keyCode = (evt.keyCode)? evt.keyCode : evt.getKeyCode();

    switch (keyCode) {
        case "N".charCodeAt(0):
            player.motion = motionType.LEFT;
            break;

        case "M".charCodeAt(0):
            player.motion = motionType.RIGHT;
            break;


        // Add your code here
        case "Z".charCodeAt(0):
        if (player.isOnPlatform()) {
          //Jump
          player.verticalSpeed = JUMP_SPEED;
        }
            break;


    }
}


//
// This is the keyup handling function for the SVG document
//
function keyup(evt) {
    // Get the key code
    var keyCode = (evt.keyCode)? evt.keyCode : evt.getKeyCode();

    switch (keyCode) {
        case "N".charCodeAt(0):
            if (player.motion == motionType.LEFT) player.motion = motionType.NONE;
            break;

        case "M".charCodeAt(0):
            if (player.motion == motionType.RIGHT) player.motion = motionType.NONE;
            break;
    }
}


//
// This function updates the position and motion of the player in the system
//
function gamePlay() {
    // Check whether the player is on a platform
    var isOnPlatform = player.isOnPlatform();

    // Update player position
    var displacement = new Point();

    // Move left or right
    if (player.motion == motionType.LEFT)
        displacement.x = -MOVE_DISPLACEMENT;
    if (player.motion == motionType.RIGHT)
        displacement.x = MOVE_DISPLACEMENT;

    // Fall
    if (!isOnPlatform && player.verticalSpeed <= 0) {
        displacement.y = -player.verticalSpeed;
        player.verticalSpeed -= VERTICAL_DISPLACEMENT;
    }

    // Jump
    if (player.verticalSpeed > 0) {
        displacement.y = -player.verticalSpeed;
        player.verticalSpeed -= VERTICAL_DISPLACEMENT;
        if (player.verticalSpeed <= 0)
            player.verticalSpeed = 0;
    }

    // Get the new position of the player
    var position = new Point();
    position.x = player.position.x + displacement.x;
    position.y = player.position.y + displacement.y;

    // Check collision with platforms and screen
    player.collidePlatform(position);
    player.collideScreen(position);

    // Set the location back to the player object (before update the screen)
    player.position = position;

    updateScreen();
}


//
// This function updates the position of the player's SVG object and
// set the appropriate translation of the game screen relative to the
// the position of the player
//
function updateScreen() {
    // Transform the player
    player.node.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + player.position.x + "," + player.position.y + ")");

    // Calculate the scaling and translation factors

    // Add your code here

}
```

Comment: How are you linking the javascript file to the SVG file?

Comment: Please see the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456304/calling-javascript-function-from-svg-file

Comment: I'm actually quite new to web development, and got most of the code handed to me by my professor. The only link I see to the JavaScript file in the SVG file is onload="top.load(evt)" in the <svg>. In the JavaScript file, the SVG file is linked with var svgdoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function in the parent html document from an embedded svg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485232/how-to-call-a-function-in-the-parent-html-document-from-an-embedded-svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script tag needs to go in the SVG file (game.svg) and not in the html file. Note that [SVG script](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html#ScriptElement) tags use xlink:href instead of src as the attribute that holds the script source.

```
 <script xlink:href="game.js"></script>
```

You should also change `onload="top.load(evt)"` to just `onload="load(evt)"` in the root `<svg>` element.

And your third and main issue is that you have a function zoom() and a variable called zoom on line 114. Remove the variable as it isnt used and the zoom method will get called.

Comment: Adding that line to the SVG file doesn't seem to help any. Still get the same error message. Tried with both keeping the <script language="JavaScript" src="game.js"></script> in the HTML file and without it. No difference.

Comment: And that's where the error was, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is now working! At the same time I need to ask, what is the difference between the top.load(evt) and the load(evt)?

Comment: top means look for the function in the container (i.e. the script would need to be in the html file) without it the script needs to be in the SVG file.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Again, thank you for your help and explanation, it is much appreciated :)